# Question about Field Extensions' Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, group-isomorphism

The following is a paragraph of a text I'm not understanding

"Definition: An isomorphism between two field extensions $i:K→K'$, $j:L→L'$ is a pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ of field isomorphisms $\alpha:K→L$, $\beta:K'→K$, such that

$$j\big(\alpha(k)\big)=\beta\big(i(k)\big)$$

(...)

Various identifications may be made. If we identify $K$ and $i(K)$, and $L$ and $j(L)$, then $i$ and $j$ are inclusions, and the commutativity condition now becomes

$$\beta|_K=α$$

where $\beta|_K$ denotes the restriction of $\beta$ on $K$."

---

There are a few things I don't get about the latter text.

$Q1$: What is the meaning of 'identifying' a Field? If it's not too much to ask, could someone provide some example, they usually help a lot.

$Q2$: to say that $i$ and $j$ are inclusion is simply to say that (I guess that under some circumstances) $i(k) = k$, for $k∈K$ right?

$Q3$: to say that $\beta|_K=\alpha$ simply means that (I guess, again, that under some circumstances) $\beta(k) = \alpha(k)$, for $k∈K$, right?

---

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts

Comment: $i,j$ are just the identity.

Answer (score 1):

1) Making helpful (but technically incorrect) identifications is very common and useful in algebra. For example, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the ring of polynomials in $x$ with integer coefficients doesn't technically contain $\mathbb{Z}$ but we make the identification of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the constant polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. A field identification is an analogous concept.

2). Yes

3). Yes

Comment: But what does it mean to identify some algebraic structure? I literally don't know the meaning of the word on this context.

Comment: @Leo You can identify a group/ring/field $X$ with its image under an injective homomorphism since no information is lost. "Identify", as far as I know, is not a rigorous mathematical term. People just want to (falsely) view some things as subsets as others. However, people commonly do identify an object with its image under an injective homomorphism.